# How to kill an app in LineageOS 18 (Android 11) by holding the back button

Tags: lineageos, task-management, developer-options, force-close, force-stop

How can I kill an app by holding the back button in Lineage OS 18?

One of the first things I've always done when installing a new Android was to enable developer options, then scroll down to the very bottom and enable the toggle for `Kill app back button"

> Kill the foreground app by long-pressing the back button

I just upgraded to LineageOS 18, and I was very sad to discover that this option is missing!

How can I replace this functionality on LineageOS 18 so that I can force-close misbehaving apps by holding down the back button?

Comment: I don't thin that this is an AOSP feature (it seems to be a LineageOS feature). Based on your recent questions I assume that you were using LineageOS on your old phone? Have you also installed LineageOS on your new phone?

Comment: Yes, both are LineageOS. I upgraded from Lineage 15 (Android 8) to Lineage 18 (Android 11) and the option disappeared :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable this feature in newer versions of LineageOS, go to

> `Settings` -> `System` -> `Buttons` -> `Back long press action` = `Kill foreground app`

It appears it was moved from `Developer options` section to the `Buttons` section.